# Running Webcam with multiple applications

Tags: windows-7, webcam, task-scheduler

I am running [YAWCAM](http://www.yawcam.com/) as a service, no GUI. The thing is, a webcam cannot interact with multiple softwares by default.

**So, is there a way to enable multiple connections to the same webcam via software?**

I want to know if I can do something or get a software which allows me to use multiple instances of the same webcam. Preferred with no constantly configuration, just set up the essential one time and never touch it any more.

Comment: https://splitcamera.com/

Answer (score 5):

I recommend to use the free and open source software, [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/).

There is an [OBS VirtualCam plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/) which enables to create a virtual camera which can be used by other apps, for free, with no odious "watermark". I tested it just now, and it works great.

Comment: This is good but not sufficient if you want to use OBS itself at the same time e.g. for recording but not use the video output of OBS via the OBS virtual camera in your other application.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to direct the same webcam output to multiple programs at at the same time. You can use [ManyCam](http://manycam.com/) to do this.

They have a free version available, but I think the free version will show their logo (I'm not sure if there is a way to remove it in the free version). Otherwise it works great.

Comment: I've edited the question half an hour ago, preventing from this answer. First, their logo... second, trying to use it here, and it does not create the devices correctly, show only an image. I starting to prefer the second option actually, windows tasks...

Comment: Ok it looks like the logo can be removed, see here: http://blog.manycam.com/removing-the-manycam-logo/

Comment: As for it only showing an image, I vaguely remember having a similar problem when I used it for the first time, but I remember that after looking at all of their provided options I was able to solve it. Perhaps rechecking all the settings would help, may be there is something that you overlooked. If not, I will recheck the manycam software settings and get back to this question sometime later

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have come to yet is XSplit VCam. On running a programme, it automatically starts and install the virtual camera driver. Give it a try!

Comment: I could not read from the product description that it allows using its video output in multiple applications at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used splitcam for this: https://splitcam.com/
This is freeware.
(I am not affiliated to this product)

Comment: You also need to disclose your affiliation.

Comment: I am not affiliated.

Comment: If the link becomes dead then the software might be dead as well and the answer useless.